# How often do you use "can('t) have done" structure?

Tags: modal-verbs, present-perfect

How often do you use "*can('t) have done*" structure? I have read and watched relatively enough but my eye and ear are not accustomed to it.

> He can't have been at the meeting, he's on a business trip this week.
>
> They can't have bought it today because the shops are closed.
>
> I don't think I can have been listening to the same debate.
>
> How our usage can have gone from under 2Gb monthly to over 15Gb.

Comment: You should use *couldn't have*, not *can't have*.

Comment: The editors of the Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary obviously don't know what they should and shouldn't use. They included an example there: [He can't really have meant that.](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/can)

Comment: @WendiKidd - In *He can't have been at the meeting* I think the present tense is normal when you are concerned with the current consequences or conditions of his being at the meeting - as here, where his being on a business trip is still current, or in *He can't have been at the meeting, or he'd know his project is about to be cancelled.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He **must have been** at the meeting.

We use this modal to express logical deduction in an affirmative sense.

I am quite certain that he was at the meeting

He **can't have been** at the meeting.

This modal expresses logical deduction in a negative sense.

I am quite certain that he was not at the meeting.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at a corpus of my own online communications from over the last three years; out of about 400,000 lines, I found 9 instances of this construction. That works out to an average of 3 times per year. So the answer is *"not all that often, but often enough"*.

To put that another way: this construction may not be used every day, but as an English Language Learner, it's something you need to recognize.